# Regex find all parts of string surrounded with same chars

Tags: regex

I have a binary string. Is there any way to find all `0`of string surrounded with `1` using regular expressions?
For example: given string `10010001` and the result should be two matches: `00` and `000`.
I have tried `1(0+)1` pattern but it returns only `00`. I guess it's because it can't handle common symbol `1` between `00` and `000` in given example.

Comment: You need lookahead and lookbehind (specify your flavor!), and "I have tried 1(0+)1 pattern but it returns only 00" is impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use lookarounds.

```
(?<=1)0+(?=1)
```

Since lookarounds won't match any single character, you should get two matches.

*or*

You may use any one of the two (lookahead or lookbehind). In the below example, I used positive lookahead.

```
1(0+)(?=1)
```

Get the string you want from group index 1.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gS7hB2/1)

Comment: Thnak you. It worked. Sorry for that question. Maybe it's trivial but I am not so specialized in regular expressions.